# Why does the 'favored' rating change from start of game to end of game in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

Why is it when I start a game and it says the team is 'Favored' or 'Slightly Favored' and then it ends and it is considered even or even my team 'Slightly Favored'?  What impacts this?  I win where the other team is 'Favored' and I am expecting big points and then it ends and it says 'Even' and I get like 10 points for the win.

**EDIT:** Ran some tests today in 4v4:

```
Start                        End
-----                        ---
Favored Other                Even
Slightly Favored Other       Even
Slightly Favored Other       Even
Even                         Even
Even                         Even
Even                         Even
Slightly Favored Other       Even
Even                         Even
Slightly Favored Other       Slightly Favored Other
Even                         Even
Slightly Favored Me          Slightly Favored Me
Favored Other                Even
Even                         Even
```

So 5 out of 13 matches, the end weighting did not match the start weighting.  Run your own tests in 4s and see what results you get.

Comment: Do you accept answers without any sources whatsoever?

Comment: @heishe why should that matter?  Looking for general answers.. if I think your answer has value you will at least get an upvote :P

Comment: @heishe Personal experience and observation is a source. Even with outside sources, they aren't always reliable and some answers cannot really be confirmed anyways. Even if you can't cite any specific sources, as long as your answer addresses the question, it doesn't matter and may well lead to a more complete answer from someone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The discrepancy of the favored indicator before and after the match is listed as a **known bug** in a message from Blizzard Employee Huginncord (Quality Assurance) in the thread "[Known Issues 1.4.3 [Updated: 4/11/2012]](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2267599524)" on the blizzard forum.

The exact quote is as follows:

> • **Favored messaging in the load screen sometimes doesn't match the
>   favored messaging in the score screen.**
>
> We're investigating reports
>   regarding inconsistent messaging in regards to the Favored status of
>   player teams on the load screen when compared to Favored status on the
>   Score Screen. Thank you for your patience while we look into potential
>   causes for this inconsistency.

Comment: This still is not fixed. It seems they will either leave it as is or it has very low priority.

Answer (score 3):

Blizzard's servers update all MMRs (matchmaking ratings) of all players in specific intervals, to minimize the strain on their servers (This is what I know for a fact, everything after this is my personal theory).

The specific intervall times are not known, but let's say they update everything every 15 minutes, and you play your match during those 15 minutes, what you will see at the end of the game is your updated MMR.

Comment: How do you know this for fact? "Blizzard's servers update all MMRs (matchmaking ratings) of all players in specific intervals, to minimize the strain on their servers"
-Without the source that is...

Comment: There was an in-depth analysis by someone over at teamliquid.net for this a whole while ago (a year or so ago). Since I don't remember the topic of the thread anymore I have no way of finding it. That's why I asked Kelsey if he welcomed answers without (external) sources.

Comment: Ah, ok. However, unless the thread from teamliquid had inside information or learned from the company itself, I don't know if you can call it fact. It is all speculation, however much it is true or false.

Comment: But +1 nevertheless

Comment: It can be deduced that MMR changes are done periodically, not in real-time. I don't remember the exact reasoning though...